# python FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] with absolute path and file exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, minikube

I'm running a Python script as a Kubernetes job. But I'm having the next issue. I've already tried with `chmod -R 777 /home/vagrant/` but it doesn't make the script run successfully.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "app.py", line 28, in main
    config.load_kube_config(config_file=kubeconfig)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 470, in load_kube_config
    config_persister=config_persister)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py", line 427, in _get_kube_config_loader_for_yaml_file
    with open(filename) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/vagrant/.kube/config'
```

As you can see the script fails supousedly because such file doesn't exists, but when I do an `ls` the file shows that it does exists.

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/podsLister$ kubectl delete job pod-lister
job.batch "pod-lister" deleted
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/podsLister$ ls /home/vagrant/.kube/
cache  config  http-cache
```

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question, but, just to be safe, given that you're doing Kubernetes stuff… is the script actually running on the same machine as the shell you're doing `ls` in?

Comment: Meanwhile, any chance there are any non-printable characters in the Python script, or in the filename? You can check with `print(repr(filename))` in the script, and `ls /home/vagrant/.kube/config` in the shell. Again, probably not the issue, but easy to rule out, so worth ruling out…

Comment: Yes, I'm running all from the same `ssh` session. The only difference would be that `app.py` is running in a Docker container managed by Kubernetes. And I don't think so, if I manually run the commands in a python console, it works just fine. That's the weird thing

Comment: OK, if you're running the script inside the container, it's seeing the container's filesystem, not the host machine's filesystem. And that's the problem: the file doesn't exist inside the container. If you _intended_ it to (e.g., you wanted part of the external filesystem to be mounted as part of the container's), that's the part you need to fix.

Comment: You can verify this by shelling into the container and doing the `ls` there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the script is running inside a Docker container. That container has its own filesystem, not the filesystem of whatever machine happens to be hosting it. That is, in fact, most of the *point* of containers: they act like an isolated, separate computer, without you needing an *actual* separate computer.

The solution is a little less obvious, because it's not clear why you expected this to work, or what you're trying to do. Things that might make sense include:

- Changing your docker build script to copy the file into the container.
- Setting up host file sharing, so part of the real machine's filesystem is available to containers, then making the container mount that.
- Setting up "normal" file sharing, so part of the real machine's filesystem is available to anyone on the network, then making the container mount that.
- Using some higher-level feature like Kubernetes ConfigMaps to expose the file to containers.

Comment: The idea is to run a Kubernetes job that list all the pods in all namespaces. It's not as easy as doing some ConfigMaps (as I've been reading) because I need a few config files. Thanks for the help